# Trying to connect postgres database - connection url

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to conenct to postgres database on a device running ubuntu.

It says "***You are connected to database "template1" as user "postgres" via socket in "/var/run/postgresql" at port "5432".***"

I guessed that is ok but its not connecting. What is wrong? here is the connection code:

```
var dbpool, _ = pgxpool.Connect(context.Background(), os.Getenv("postgres:///template1?host=/var/run/postgresql"))
```

error from go code

```
var dbpool, _ = pgxpool.Connect(context.Background(), os.Getenv("postgres://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fpostgresql/template1"))  
func HelloServer(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(req.Body)
    var t test_struct
    err := decoder.Decode(&t)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    log.Println(t)
_, err = dbpool.Exec(ctx,"INSERT INTO users (id,name,surname) VALUES ($1,$2,$3)", t.Id, t.Name,t.Surname)
```

> runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
> goroutine 7 [running]: net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc000092dc0)
> /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1824 +0x153 panic(0x7ea0e0,
> 0xad7860)     /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:971 +0x499
> github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/pgxpool.(*Pool).Acquire(0x0, 0x8cd250,
> 0xc0000240e0, 0x10, 0x7ffa25841108, 0x10)
> /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4@v4.11.0/pgxpool/pool.go:380
> +0x31 github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/pgxpool.(*Pool).Exec(0x0, 0x8cd250, 0xc0000240e0, 0x85f063, 0x36, 0xc000103aa8, 0x3, 0x3, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
> /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4@v4.11.0/pgxpool/pool.go:432
> +0x86 main.HelloServer(0x8cbcc0, 0xc0000e22a0, 0xc000134100)  /root/goservertls.go:41 +0x2b1
> net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x86d7e0, 0x8cbcc0, 0xc0000e22a0,
> 0xc000134100)     /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2069 +0x44
> net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0xae6be0, 0x8cbcc0, 0xc0000e22a0,
> 0xc000134100)     /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2448 +0x1ad
> net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc0000e20e0, 0x8cbcc0, 0xc0000e22a0,
> 0xc000134100)     /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2887 +0xa3
> net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc000092dc0, 0x8cd2c0, 0xc0000634c0)
> /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1952 +0x8cd created by
> net/http.(*Server).Serve  /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:3013
> +0x39b

Answer (score 1):

The host needs to go in the host position of the URI, not just tacked on at the end.  But since it includes literal `/`, those need to be URI encoded.

```
 postgres://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fpostgresql/template1
```